# Webview reloadIgnoringCache() not working

Tags: webview, electron, browser-cache, reload, cache-control

I tried `@wv[0].loadURL(@wv[0].src, {extraHeaders: 'pragma: no-cache\n'})`
and also

```
@wv[0]?.reloadIgnoringCache()
```

but both are not working, I am trying to achieve live reload of current document. Let say current document is index.html and it has scripts and css file, now when I update scripts and css files and reload index.html in webview, it doesn’t update css and script files at all. However It does update content of index.html only

Any idea?

Comment: Are they updated in Chrome with ctrl+F5?

Comment: they are working fine in chrome browser but not in atom webview